# next and prev button Plot in shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, graphics

in R, we have "next" and "previous" button to show another plot, but how about shiny? This is just sample plot, in real case I have more than 30 plot, so I can't call one by one. Can I made button next prev in plot shiny? Thankyou for helping.. [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmMGm.jpg)

Comment: Your question is not quite clear about what you want. Shiny like having components react to your input - you move a slider etc and the plot updates. Should moving back in the plot history also change these inputs? Should all intermediate versions created by moving a slider be saved as well, and if not, how should a "complete" plot be identified?

Comment: This may help: https://yonicd.github.io/slickR/index.html